# python string manipulation with format command

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the follow python code but i dont know what it is doing, can someone help me understand what it is doing please?  I've googled but i dont know what im searching for..

```
single_line = "1562661"
single_line = '{:<07}'.format(single_line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this particular code of your is used to add extra spaces if your string size exceeds 7.

Example 1

```
single_line = "1562661"
single_line = '{:<07}'.format(single_line)

for ex: This code above will give us

'1562661'
```

Example 2

```
single_line = "1562661"
single_line = '{:<10}'.format(single_line)

'1562661   '(This will be genererated by the code above with 3 trailing spaces)
```

Example 3:

```
single_line = "1562661"
single_line = '{:>10}'.format(single_line)

'   1562661'(This will be genererated by the code above with 3 leading spaces)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [docs](https://pyformat.info/):

> **Padding and aligning strings**
>
> By default values are formatted to take
> up only as many characters as needed to represent the content. It is
> however also possible to define that a value should be padded to a
> specific length.
>
> Unfortunately the default alignment differs between old and new style
> formatting. The old style defaults to right aligned while for new
> style it's left.

Example:

```
single_line = "123"
single_line = '{:<07}'.format(single_line)
```

Results in :

> '1230000'